# mongodb ruby :Updating a field within a nested document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, updates

I have a document in mongodb with the following structure.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52ad477a5873b710c0000007"),
"ad_name" : "name_6",
"selected" : true,
"vendor" : "facebook.com",
"status" : "VALID",
"ad_details" : {
    "Body" : "something",
    "Title" : "random_6",
    "Url" : "www.someurl.com",
    "Image" : "blob_data"
     }
}
```

i want to update the field name "selected" and the field "Url" in one query.Currently i can update selected field but not Url.

```
ads.update({"_id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(doc_id)},
                            {"$set"=> {"selected" => select, "Url" => params["urls"][indx]}}
```

This query does not give me any error but doesnt update the Url as it is present inside ad_details sub-document. Also i DO NOT WANT to update entire ad_details json which is one way of doing it.Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the path to the value you want to update:

```
'$set' => { 'ad_details.Url' => params['urls'][idx], ... }
```